# Handle duplication when application polling in cloud

Tags: spring, design-patterns, google-cloud-platform, architecture

We have a scenario that we need to check after some interval that whether all the results are completed/processed in db against a particular id or not, and if it is then we need to make a file and send it to some bucket.

This logic is written in spring application. Now the problem is I have a concern that once we deploy that application to cloud than if there are 10 instances running of an application then there is a chance that the file could be placed multiple times on the bucket.

I don't want to implement something outside of an application (but open to any suggestion if it's not possible). May be using some db flags could help but I think that is not right or messy as all instances would be processing something before checking  at the end that the file is already processed.

Please let me know on this. Thanks!

P.S. I am using Spring, Mongodb, and GCP as cloud provider.

Comment: there's no silver bullet to make things concurrency-aware if that was not considered during the design phase. Usually you need a single dispatcher which manages a jobs queue and it can offload the tasks from there to multiple workers (ie. your 10 instance).

Comment: Is it possible to name your file close to your business something like "product-id" "sales-id" ? In that case, you can make sure your cloud provider(bucket) to not support duplicate file names. Then whatever comes first, that will succeed others will fail and you can gracefully handle them in spring. One problem could be waste of time and energy for generating and sending file to cloud provider, but you wouldn't need database flag. I am not sure if this is right approach, but maybe something you can consider of if needed.

Comment: You can also send an event to the queue once processing is finished and connect that queue to all your spring applications, in this case only one application can read the message and publish to cloud provider and delete that event in the queue.

Comment: unfortunately the naming convention is filename-(System Time In Millis) so we can't go for replacing file on bucket. And doesn't have better way other than polling. I guess some dedicated external service would be the only way for that.

Comment: I agree with what is mentioned above. I don't even know if your application is hosted on App Engine, but I think you can have a look at [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks) and find out if it suits your business requirements. _You can create App Engine tasks and place them in Cloud Tasks queues. Using this process you can explicitly specify the service and handler that should process the task, and optionally pass task-specific data along to the handler._